# Are the Powerset of a Set and all Permutations of a Set equivalent?

Tags: notation, set-theory, game-theory

I'm reading the original [Shapley values paper](https://books.google.co.uk/books?hl=en&lr=&id=mkT_DwAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA69&dq=A%20Value%20for%20n-Person%20Games&ots=nyVwrD2THd&sig=6X7ZKtXjd0uY2zNQlQBUOWHxh0Q&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=A%20Value%20for%20n-Person%20Games&f=false), page 70, which was published in 1953. In this paper Shapley writes the following:

[image]

where $U$ is the "universe of all players" that can take part in a game, in other words, the set of all players. From the description, I think $\Pi(U)$ is meant to denote the powerset of $U$, $\mathcal P(U)$, and $\Pi$ is an old out-of-use notation. Can anybody confirm?

Comment: No, they are not at all equivalent.  Compare: $\mathcal{P}(\{1,2,3\}) = \{\emptyset,\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$ has $2^3=8$ elements.  Meanwhile $\Pi(\{1,2,3\}) = \{(1,2,3),(1,3,2),(2,1,3),(2,3,1),(3,1,2),(3,2,1)\}$ has $3!=6$ elements (*using sequence notation for the permutations.  recall, these are technically functions and sequences are formally defined as functions*)

Comment: No, they are not the same set in general. For example, if $|U|=n$ then $|\Pi\left(U\right)=n!| and $|P(U)|=2^n $.

Comment: @JMoravitz I see, so ordering doesn't matter in a set, but $\Pi(U)$ doesn't produce sets, it produces a set of permutations?

Comment: Correct, and I need to really stress the fact that although we may often write permutations as sequences or ordered tuples or strings and the like out of convenience... they are in this context *functions* who have both domain and codomain $U$ and who are bijective.  This allows you to compose permutations to get another permutation, etc...  See also the [Symmetric Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group).  It takes a lot less space and effort to write $(1,3,2)$ than to write $f(x) = \begin{cases}1&\text{if }x=1\\3&\text{if }x=2\\2&\text{if }x=3\end{cases}$

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you, that adds a lot of clarity. I wasn't aware of permutations technically being functions.

Comment: From an algebraic point of view or set theoretic point of view, they certainly are.  The word "permutation" has been bastardized and used incorrectly so many times lately that it has gained the extra, less rigorous, meaning of "arrangement of objects" and has in those contexts sometimes even lost the requirement that each object be unique and that each object appears exactly once (*no more and no less*) in each such arrangement.  I would encourage you and anyone else reading this to avoid using the word in such a context and use the more generic word "arrangement" instead.

Comment: @JMoravitz I have a follow up question on the application of permutation functions to set functions, which is related to this question. You were so helpful on this, would you be willing to take a look? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4631071/what-happens-when-you-apply-a-permutation-function-to-a-set-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The powerset $\mathcal P(U)$ is the set of *subsets* of $U$. The *permutations* of $U$ are different objects.

For an example,
$$\mathcal P(\{1,2\})=\big\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\big\}$$
consists of the $2^2=4$ subsets of $\{1,2\}$, while
$$\Pi(\{1,2\})=\big\{(12),(21)\big\},$$
where $(12)$ denotes the function sending $1\to 1$ and $2\to 2$, while $(21)$ denotes the function sending $2\to 1$ and $1\to 2$. In general, if $U$ is a finite set of size $n$, then $\mathcal P(U)$ has $2^n$ elements, while $\Pi(U)$ has $n!$ elements.

Comment: Thank you. Is $\Pi(U)$ the general way of writing this in set notation?

Comment: @Connor I've sometimes seen it as $S(U)$ or $\operatorname{Sym}(U)$, but since $\pi$ is a common letter for permutations, $\Pi(U)$ strikes me as reasonable notation for this.