# What happens when you apply a Permutation function to a Set-function?

Tags: notation, permutations, game-theory

This question is motivated by the original [Shapley values paper](https://books.google.co.uk/books?hl=en&lr=&id=mkT_DwAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA69&dq=A%20Value%20for%20n-Person%20Games&ots=nyVwrD2THd&sig=6X7ZKtXjd0uY2zNQlQBUOWHxh0Q&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=A%20Value%20for%20n-Person%20Games&f=false). On page 70 of this paper, Shapley defines a set of [permutation functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4630459/are-the-powerset-of-a-set-and-all-permutations-of-a-set-equivalent) $\pi$:

> Let $\Pi(U)$ denote the set of permutations of $U$ - that is, the one to one mappings of $U$ onto itself. If $\pi \in \Pi(U)$, then, writing $\pi S$ for the image of $S$ under $\pi$, we may define the function $\pi v$ by: $$\pi v(\pi S) = v(S) \;\;\;\;\;\; (\text{all} \; S \subseteq U )$$

where $U$ is the "universe of all possible players", and $S$ is a subset of all those players. $\Pi (U)$ represents the set of all the possible orderings of players in the universe of players $U$. $v$ is a "superadditive set-function" defined by Shapley as:

> $$ v(0) = 0 \\ v(S) \geq v(S \cap T) + v(S - T) \;\;\;\;\; (\text{all}\; S,T \subseteq U).$$

As you can see, $\pi$ can be applied to either $S$ or $v$. The former case is represented by $\pi S$ and makes intuitive sense to me, the function rearranges the elements of the set $S$ into some definite order and returns it.

However, I find the latter case confusing. Applying $\pi$ to something seems to imply that you're rearranging its elements into some definite order. What does that mean when it's applied to the superadditive set function $v$, giving $\pi v$?

Comment: Please, add the context missing (what is $v$?). The questions shouldn't depend on links to be understood. Also, avoid the use of images. Type your question so the text can be searched and seen in every device.

Comment: The definition of $\pi v$ is given in the pictured quote.  If you want intuition as to what it does... you can think of it as though $\pi v$ is the same as $v$ with the exception that $\pi v$ uses the changed labels while $v$ uses the original labels.  It reminds me of using "change of basis matrices" in linear algebra, though the notation is different.

Comment: If you want an explicit example, consider keeping things small and tangible.  Let $U=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and let $\pi$ be the transposition that just swaps $1$ and $2$.  Finally, let $v$ be the function $v(x)=x^2$.  Then, for a given $S$ we have $v(S)$ is the set of squares of elements in $S$... such as $v(\{2,3,4\})=\{4,9,16\}$.  Meanwhile $\pi(\{2,3,4\})=\{1,3,4\}$.  We have $\pi v(\pi S)=\{4,9,16\}$ here, by definition.

Comment: Now... I'll leave it to you to try to reason whether this should be that $(\pi v )(x)$ should equal $v(\pi (x))$ or if it should equal $v(\pi^{-1}(x))$.  For an example like a transposition, we would have had that $\pi = \pi^{-1}$, so maybe try thinking of a slightly larger example if you need to.  Otherwise, consider using algebra.

Comment: @JMoravitz I think $(\pi v)(x) = v(\pi(x))$, do I have it right? My intuition is that applying $\pi$ to the function $v$ applies a transformation to the input set before running it through $v$. In this case, that would mean that given a set of players $S$, and a permutation function $\pi$ that is $U \mapsto U$, $\pi v$ can take $S$ but the players who actually play the game $v$ don't have to be in $S$, they could be any of the players in $U$. The only thing that's preserved is the cardinality of $S$.

Comment: Recall that $\pi v(\pi S) = v(S)$.  Recall also that $\pi^{-1}\pi S = S$, but $\pi\pi S$ might not equal $S$

Comment: Without being explicit and saying $(\pi v)(\pi S)$ what is the assumed order of operation? Is $\pi$ applied to $v$ before $\pi v$ is applied to $(\pi S)$?